# Error tying to update the camel version of my spring application from camel-3.0.0 to 3.18.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, apache-camel

The error is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'camel-1': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: log
Build.gradle file for the project is :
The versions used are
org.springframework.boot : 2.6.8
io.spring.dependency-management : 1.1.0
and java : 17

Gradle Dependencies are:

`

```
dependencies {
implementation platform('org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-spring-boot-bom:3.18.0')
implementation 'org.apache.camel:camel-bom:3.18.0'
implementation 'org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-spring-boot-starter:3.18.0'
implementation 'org.apache.camel:camel-rabbitmq:3.18.0'
implementation 'org.apache.camel:camel-jackson:3.18.0'
implementation 'org.apache.camel:camel-gson:3.18.0'
implementation 'org.apache.camel:camel-jetty:3.18.0'
implementation 'org.apache.camel:camel-netty:3.18.0'
implementation 'org.apache.camel:camel-netty-http:3.18.0'
implementation 'org.apache.camel:camel-swagger-java:3.18.0'
implementation 'org.apache.camel:camel-jpa:3.18.0'
implementation 'org.apache.camel:camel-dozer:3.18.0'
implementation 'org.apache.camel:camel-spring-security:3.18.0'
implementation 'org.apache.camel:camel-jsonpath:3.18.0'
implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:2.6.8'
implementation 'com.zaxxer:HikariCP:3.3.1'
implementation 'org.apache.camel:camel-properties:3.0.0-RC1'
implementation('org.apache.camel:camel-core:3.18.0') {
exclude group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', module: 'log4j-core'
}
implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.8'
implementation 'com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-52:1.0.0'
implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.1'
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.9'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.10.0'
implementation 'javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:2.2'
implementation 'io.swagger:swagger-annotations:1.5.23'
implementation 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:9.4.21.v20190926'
implementation 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:9.4.21.v20190926'
implementation 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:9.4.21.v20190926'
implementation 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:9.4.21.v20190926'
implementation 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:9.4.21.v20190926'
implementation 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:9.4.21.v20190926'
implementation 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:9.4.21.v20190926'
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4'
implementation 'javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final'
implementation 'org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:6.0.13.Final'

testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Can you share the setting.yaml . The exception strace is not there so it will be hard to find, can u add it.